# Matplotlibで描画したdendrogramのlabelが重なってしまう

Tags: matplotlib, python3

Matplotlibでdendrogramを描画すると、nodeが多い場合はlabelが重なって見えづらくなってしまうことがあると思います。
単純にfigureのsizeを拡大することで対処しようと思ったのですが、
plt.figure(figsize=x,y))のx, yをどれだけ大きくしても、スクリーンの大きさ以上にならずlabelが重なったままです。
対処方法をご存知でしたらご教示いただけますと幸いです。
Pythonのverは3.6.0です。

```
from scipy.spatial.distance import pdist
from scipy.cluster.hierarchy import linkage, dendrogram
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.figure(figsize=(16,9))
plt.title("Title")
plt.xlabel("xlabel", fontsize=10)
plt.ylabel("ylabel", fontsize=10)
plt.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.35)
dendrogram(linkage(xxxxxx), labels=list(xxxxxx), leaf_font_size=8, leaf_rotation=90)
plt.savefig("filename")
plt.show()
```

Comment: フォントサイズを小さくするのはだめですか?

Comment: takoikaさんありがとうございます、フォントサイズを小さくするのはありなのですが6ptくらいで限界なので、figure自体を大きくする方法と併用したいと思っています。